# angular comparing two array values using ngIf else to show button

Tags: arrays, node.js, angular

I am working on two arrays with ngIf else condition , I got two array values from two tables posts[post_id, user_id, description], likes[post_id, user_id, like_status, like_id].Here i need to compare post_id, user_id and like_status='like' if they are equal then condition true show success button else false default button.

I am already tried but its not working so please help to compare two arrays in using ngIf else .

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index">
   <h6> {{post.description}} </h6>

    <div class="container" style="border: 0px solid #ada5a5; ">
        <div class="row">

          <!--like button-->
          <div class=" col-4">

              <div *ngIf="(postLikes.indexOf(user_id) > -1) && (post.post_id == postLikes.post_id) && (postLikes.like_status == 'like'); else default">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Liked</button><p>liked</p>
              </div>
                <ng-template #default>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)>Like</button><p>like</p>
                </ng-template>
         </div>

        </div>

      </div>


  </div>


// two tables data
  posts: any[] =
    [{
    "post_id": 4,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " Hi How are you ",
    "created_date": "2019-01-28T12:30:49.000Z"
}, {
    "post_id": 5,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " Working a Fine ",
    "created_date": "2019-01-28T12:31:20.000Z"
}, {
    "post_id": 6,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " Hi How are you ......",
    "created_date": "2019-01-28T12:32:15.000Z"
}, {
    "post_id": 7,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " 4th test post",
    "created_date": "2019-01-29T07:10:37.000Z"
}, {
    "post_id": 9,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " 5th test post",
    "created_date": "2019-01-31T11:17:31.000Z"
}, {
    "post_id": 10,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " 6th test post",
    "created_date": "2019-01-31T12:03:54.000Z"
}, {
    "post_id": 11,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " 7th post post",
    "created_date": "2019-02-08T05:50:02.000Z"
}, {
    "post_id": 12,
    "user_id": 2,
    "description": " 8th test post ",
    "created_date": "2019-02-08T06:08:01.000Z"
}];

  postLikes:any[] =[{
    "post_id": 4,
    "user_id": 2,
    "like_status": "unlike",
    "like_id": 10
}, {
    "post_id": 5,
    "user_id": 2,
    "like_status": "like",
    "like_id": 9
}, {
    "post_id": 6,
    "user_id": 2,
    "like_status": "like",
    "like_id": 8
}, {
    "post_id": 7,
    "user_id": 2,
    "like_status": "like",
    "like_id": 7
}, {
    "post_id": 9,
    "user_id": 2,
    "like_status": "like",
    "like_id": 11
}];
  post_id: any;
  user_id:Number = 2;
  // likes: Like[];
  like_id: number | null ;
  like_status: string;
```

Please try my StackBlitz code once and correct the error

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wddupe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: length of `posts` array and `postLikes` are always same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated code, please find changes

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjcpfk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with postlikes condition in html you compare string with array 
 Ngfor for postlikes array is remaining

I recommend you to do this in typescript using find keyword to compare and pass that result on posts objects like boolean from that it shows and hide your button

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this

1. Create a public method in your component as

   ```
   public isPostLikedByUser(postID: any, userID: any){
       // This is actually matching the criteria exactly as you have described in question RETURN true or false
       return this.postLikes.findIndex((i) => i.post_id == postID && i.user_id == userID && i.like_status == 'like') > -1;
   }
   ```
2. Now call this method in your view as

   ```
    <div *ngIf="isPostLikedByUser(post.post_id, post.user_id); else otherTest">
   ```

I have updated you stackblitz example as well. I hope this helps.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wddupe?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html